# Java for loop running both true and false conditions

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I refactored a working project to practice creating callable methods when I broke the app. This app includes a simple String array with a method that matches user input with the array and prints the element name and index.

If I don't include a break at the end of the if else statements the app can match valid input but runs both if and else statements. It actually prints the if statement in the order of the index and prints the else output the number of times as the length of the array. In the attached pic, the input was index 0. [if statement output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSU1w.png) In the pic index 0 was matched and printed with the number of else outputs as in the array. It seems the else statement is reading the array length.

If I add the break, the app only recognizes index 0 and will run the if statement as expected, but also runs the else statement. But only prints out if else output once. I hope this is clear.  Trainers have simply said it is impossible to for a for loop to print of which I understand, yet I'm having a different experience.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("What are you looking for? ");
    //String product = scan.nextLine();
    String[] aisles = {"apples", "bananas", "candy", "chocolate", "coffee", "tea"};
    searchProduct(aisles);
  }

  public static void searchProduct(String[] aisles) {
    String product = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < aisles.length; i++) {
      if (product.equals(aisles[i])) {
        System.out.println("We have " + aisles[i] + " in aisle " + i);

      } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry we do not have that product");

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to match valid user input and run the if statement or run the else statement.

Comment: "In the attached pic, the input was index 0." I can't understand what you mean. There is nothing in the input that says which index to look at, and the **purpose of** the loop is to look at every index. You see a separate result for each element of the array because **the loop runs multiple times (that's what a loop is for)**, and each time prints something.

Comment: Hint: on the first iteration of the loop, you really can't say "Sorry, we do not have that product". You can only accurately say that after checking *every* aisle.

Comment: "Trainers have simply said it is impossible to for a for loop to print of which I understand" This doesn't make any sense at all. Please try to write more clearly. Start by thinking about the problem, and clearly explaining: **what kinds of inputs** could we have, that are meaningfully different from each other? For each of those cases, **exactly what should happen** when the code runs?

Comment: One option is to use special value, let's say `-1`, if product is found, assign index and break loop. Do the if-else check outside the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet if I correctly guessed the (very vaguely described) problem, then it's one that huge amounts of beginners have in every programming language. We really should have some kind of language-agnostic canonical for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion.

- Change your method to return an int (`aisle` if the product exists or `-1` if not).
- Don't do any I/O in the method.  Just pass the target of the search as an argument.

```
String[] aisles = {
        "apples","bananas","candy","chocolate","coffee","tea"
};
System.out.println("What are you looking for? ");
String product = scan.nextLine();

int aisle = searchProduct(product, aisles);
if (aisle >= 0) {
    System.out.println("We have " + product + " in aisle " + aisle);
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry we do not have that product");
}
    

public static int searchProduct(String product, String[] aisles) {
    for (int aisle = 0; aisle < aisles.length; aisle++) {
        if (product.equals(aisles[aisle])) {
            return aisle;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```